# Feminine/plural for "enfant" and "parent"

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, noms

> Quand j'étais enfant, j'aimais ...

If the person is female, should we use *enfante*? Similarly, in

> Quand nous étions enfant, nous aimions ...

should we use *enfant(e)s*? *Enfant* is a noun that behaves like an adjective, so I think it should have an ending like an adjective in both cases.

Similar questions for *parent*:

> Quand je serai parent, je serai strict(e) avec mes enfants.

Do we need to use *parente* if the person is female?

> Quand nous serons parent, nous serons ...

should we use *parent(e)s*?

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing particularly adjectival about "enfant". If you're referring to the lack of an article, that's more due to the syntactic structure that seems to be used for an assertion of identity (*il est prof*, *tu es médicin*, *je suis canadien*) — the nature of which is a good question on its own.

Comment: @LukeSawczak But in those cases we have to change the ending if the noun is feminine or plural, right? (*Elle est canadienne*, *Nous sommes canadien(ne)s*) Whereas in the cases of *enfant* and *parent*, the rule seems to be different.

Comment: Formulating an answer now. :) But quickly — it's not a function of the noun/adjective status of the word in that slot. They're just nouns of different types.

Comment: @user11550 - I changed my answer a bit - I now think that _enfants_ (plural) would be more correct, or at least much more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for a girl, we say:

> Quand j'étais enfant, ...

*enfante* IMHO is not the feminine form of *enfant*. cf [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enfant).

For this one:

> Quand nous étions enfant, nous aimions ...

I would say that you have to use *enfants* (plural). I don't really see a reason that would allow you to escape the agreement - unless maybe if you considered "être enfant" to be a fixed expression. But I don't know if you would have a very strong case. However, [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quand%20nous%20%C3%A9tions%20enfant%2Cquand%20nous%20%C3%A9tions%20enfants&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquand%20nous%20%C3%A9tions%20enfant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquand%20nous%20%C3%A9tions%20enfants%3B%2Cc0) shows that both are used, with a very strong preference for *enfants* (plural). The references given by ngrams don't seem to point to the singular being only a mistake. It seems to be a true usage.

[image]

Same analysis for *parent*, except that *parente* is this time the feminine form of *parent* ([CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parente)).

Comment: Just to confirm: When you say "Same analysis for *parent*", you mean that a girl would say *Quand je serai parent*, even though the form *parente* exists, right?

Comment: @user11550 - probably. I think _parente_ is more "specialized" in a sense. I could see both being used though. But she would probably say something else, like _Quand j'aurais des enfants_, which sounds a lot more natural.

Comment: What do you mean *parente* is more "specialized"?

Comment: @user11550 - it's not a word we use a lot. _Une parente_ is OK, in e.g. _une parente du défunt_, but I wouldn't expect to hear _je suis la parente de X_, or _je vais être parente_. Actually, I think we tend to use _les parents_ in the plural more than _parent_ or _parente_ in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

This same question applies to a wide range of questions that appear to have a set gender but are clearly used for people of different genders: *enfant*, *parent*, but also *professeur* as it once was (*professeure* has existed only "[since the end of the 20th century](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeure)"). In fact, the word *personne* itself has seemingly the opposite issue for men — your average Joe is *une personne*. :)

The grammatical term for this kind of word is "epicene" and

> ... can be used in two distinct situations:
>
> - [when] the same word can refer to both masculine and feminine antecedents ...
> - [when] a noun or adjective has identical masculine and feminine forms
>     ...
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicene))

The first case would be like *personne*. No matter the gender of the person meant, the determiners, adjectives, etc. will always agree with *personne* as feminine. (At least AFAIK.)

Dictionaries often refer to this as simply "nm" or "nf", as the case may be.

The second case would be where the form is identical but the grammatical gender changes, and hence surfaces in words that agree. *Enfant* is actually the very example Wikipedia gives. It is possible to say *un enfant* or *une enfant*, and likewise *un petit enfant* vs. *une petite enfant*.

Dictionaries often refer to this as "nmf".

The third option is that there are two corresponding forms of the same word, of which one is masculine and the other is feminine. French is full of this kind of thing too. An example would be *chat* and *chatte* — or even phonologically dissimilar variants like *acteur* and *actrice*.

Dictionaries often refer to this as "nm/nf" and/or list both variants (e.g. "ours, e").

If you're unsure and your dictionary doesn't list it clearly, then as Frank has done, you can distinguish between these cases using Ngrams. For example, *parent* is listed in Collins as "parent, e". If you were trying to verify this independently, you can show that *une parente* is well attested but *une parent* is not:

[image: Distinguishing the two types of epicene]

This rules out the second case ("nmf").

However, it's a little harder to distinguish between invariant words and words with two forms. *Une parent* is out, but how do you know that you wouldn't say "C'est *un parent*" where *ce* refers to a woman? It certainly helps to know that *une parente* exists; if it didn't, we could assume *parent* was an epicene word. But between *une parente* and an invariable *un parent*, I would say it's hard to know what significance the 0.00005% usage of *une parente* has in the bigger picture without a way to disentangle the antecedent in phrases like "C'est un parent".

---

For the plural, the closest parallel term is probably [indénombrable](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ind%C3%A9nombrable). (English [count/mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) is nearly the same thing, but doesn't, to my knowledge, include an equivalent for nouns like *des pâtes* that are plural but still cannot be individually counted as e.g. *deux pâtes*.)

Luckily, nouns for people and animals in French tend to be unambiguously dénombrable.* So if your subject is plural, as *nous* is, then *enfants* is the one you want.

* Except, of course, for "le monde" and "les gens"!

Comment: For _un parent_, I think we would say _une parente_ if it was a woman. We wouldn't say _un parent_, as you say. _Nous serons parents_, symmetrical of _nous étions enfants_ works perfectly.